# How to display the image using mailing ribbon?

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

During the mail merge process using an .xlsx dataset and a .docx file, I attempted to create an ID card. While the Mailing ribbon successfully populated all the information from the .xlsx file onto the .docx file, the image did not appear. How can I ensure that the image from the .xlsx file is displayed in the .docx file?

I have tried to solve the problem using mail merge option and i kept the image location as a hyperlink on into .xlsx file.

I expect that, i can mention the image location into .xlsx file and the picture will be displayed on .docx file.